# How to Dynamically update input field value?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, jquery, inputfield

When I enter mobile number in mobile field how to auto update in Phone field same Mobile number without submitting any button in page using Script/jquery

Here Mobile is Parent(Org__c Object) field. Phone is child (Employee__c Object) field.

[image]

Comment: Did you try binding the same variable to Phone and see if it works?

Comment: i dinnt get you RedDevil, can you please share me code or urls, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can do this very easily.

I think what I would do is use jQuery and have mobile as main and then have the phone with a class.

Example:

```
$('#main').change(function() {
$('.inp').val($(this).val());
});

Mobile: <apex:inputText id="main"></>
Phone:  <apex:inputText class="inp"></>
```

You will need to add a script tags and a link to the jQuery file in your page e.g. https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js

Comment: With Visualforce elements, the ID has extra stuff in it, so you need to select the input field something like: `$('input[id$=main]')` when using jQuery.